# Photoshop CS5 issue with transparency grid

Tags: photoshop-cs5

Have a document open with no background.  The transparency grid is gone and is all black instead. What happened?

Comment: You're a bit sparse on detail. What file format is your document? Does it contain layers? What happens if you create a new transparent image in Photoshop - does it behave normally?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking *Edit » Preferences » Transparency & Gamut*.

- Grid size: Medium
- Grid colors: Light
- left color: `#ffffff`
- right color: `#cccccc`

Or maybe you created a new document and in the 'New Document Window' you have the Background Contents set to *Black* or *Background color*.